# Tensor shape must be [-1,-1,-1,3] but was [X,XXX,XXXX,X]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, discord.js

I'm new to JS (especially to Node and tfjs) and I want to convert my image into a tensor.

But whenever I try to do so, I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The shape of dict['image_tensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,-1,-1,3], but was [1,628,1100,4]
```

Here's my code:

```
async function gotMessage(msg) {
    if(msg.content === '!object')  {   
        const attachments = (msg.attachments).array();

        const filepath = "./images/" + Date.now() + "J" + ".png";
        console.log(filepath);
        const imageurl = attachments[0].url;

        await saveImageToDisk(imageurl,filepath)

        let img_buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath)
        const img = tf.node.decodePng(img_buffer)
        

        coco.load().then(model => {
            // detect objects in the image.
            model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
                console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
            });
          });
        msg.reply('Enjoy');
        msg.channel.send(attachments[0].url);
    }
}
async function saveImageToDisk(url,path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var fullUrl = url;
    var localPath = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    var request = https.get(fullUrl,function(response) { 
        //console.log(response)
        response.pipe(localPath)
        response.on('end', resolve);
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

decodePng returns a 4D array. If you want to use it for training your model, just pass
expand_animations=True to decodePng. It will return a 3D array.

[Tensorflow doc on decodePng](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image)

Comment: Would you mind showing me a way to use it in code? I've tried it but it says that the "None" parameter in channels is undefined. And when I change it to 0 it says that "uint8" is undefined.

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say "expand_animations=False", not true. True is the default.